# How to use "Adaptive Images" with images hosted on Amazon AWS Cloud?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, heroku, responsive-images

First Question: So I want to use [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/details.htm) on a website that I'm building. Problem is that my website is being hosted on Heroku, but my images live on the Amazon AWS Cloud, S3 service. How do I modify the PHP file to point to the source image files on Amazon?

Second Question: If I point the PHP file to the source images on Amazon, would I need my ai-cache folder to also be on Amazon, or could that be hosted on Heroku?

ANSWER: Please see Mark B's comment below for the answer to this question. Thanks again Mark.

Comment: "Amazon AWS Cloud" is currently comprised of over 50 different services. Which service(s) are you using to host your images? You will have to be much more specific if you want help.

Comment: @Mark B - Thanks for the response. You're totally right. Should've thought of that. Please see my edit above. Is that enough info?

Comment: That tutorial you linked is specifically for serving images via an Apache web server and requires you to configure Apache in a certain way. S3 doesn't use Apache and you don't have access to change those types of configuration settings on S3. You would have to move your images off S3 to be able to use the technique in that tutorial.

Comment: @Mark B - Ok that makes sense, but since my images only live on S3 and I'm using the PHP on Heroku (which is Apache and is configurable), plus my cache folder for the output images lives on Heroku, shouldn't I still be able to make it work? I.E. the PHP on Heroku looks for my source images on S3, grabs them and then creates output cache files that are hosted on Heroku?

Comment: Are you saying the images are actually served by Apache on Heroku, and not served to the user directly from S3?

Comment: @Mark B - Oh I see what you are saying. Looking at the documentation for A.I. again, I realize that the .htaccess that gives instructions on how to serve up the image files has to reside on the same server as the images. So, because S3 doesn't use Apache, A.I. won't work. Thanks Mark. +1